# Roots of determinant of matrix with polynomial entries — a generalization

Tags: reference-request, matrices, polynomials, determinants, zeroes

For $1 \le i, j \le k$, consider $\rho_{ij}$ which are equal to either zero or one such that $\rho_{ii}=1$ and $\rho_{ij}=0$ if and only if $\rho_{ji}=0$. How to find the zeros of the determinant of the following matrix?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
g_1(x) & -\rho_{12}f_1(x)  & \cdots & -\rho_{1,k}f_1(x)  \\
-\rho_{21}f_2(x)  & g_2(x) & \cdots & -\rho_{2,k}f_2(x) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
-\rho_{k1}f_k(x) & -\rho_{k2}f_k(x) & \cdots &g_k(x)
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $f_i$s are $g_i$s are complex polynomials.
When all the $\rho_{ij}=1$, I have got the answer in MO already at [Roots of determinant of matrix with polynomial entries](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365764). The present question is a more general case.

I am not sure whether there is any direct answer to this question. I am looking for some reference where similar kinds of problems ars discussed.

Comment: You can get an inequality using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Schur_product_theorem).