# Modeling decay of a linear system with a mixing term

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrix-analysis, laplace-transform

I'm trying to analyze convergence of $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+d}$ which follows the following recurrence

$$\mathbf{x}\leftarrow (\mathbf{1}-\mathbf{h})^2 \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{h}\rangle$$

Here $\mathbf{1}$ indicates a vector of $1$'s, vector multiplication, addition, squaring are applied pointwise and $\mathbf{h}\propto (1^{-p},2^{-p},\ldots ,d^{-p})$ for some $p\in (1,2)$.

I care about L1 norm after $t$ steps which is well approximated by the following:

$$f(t)=\|\mathbf{x}_t\|_1\approx e^{t(\operatorname{diag}[(\mathbf{1}-\mathbf{h})^2]+\mathbf{h}\mathbf{h}^T)}\mathbf{h}$$

For a given $p$, how do I get a nice upper bound on $f(t)$ which holds when $d\to \infty$?

Things are easy if we didn't have the the $\mathbf{h}\mathbf{h}^T$ term: approximating $\|\mathbf{x}_t\|_1$ with an integral I get formulas which match observed behavior very well:

[image]
<sub><sup>[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-rank1-recurrence-simple.nb)</sup></sub>

Keeping $\mathbf{h}\mathbf{h}^T$ term makes things much harder to handle. Straightforward approach [gives formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4668173/998) in terms of roots of diagonal + rank-1 matrix, but not practical for large $d$. There's also a numeric [approach](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443030/7655) which works but also leaves unclear the dependence on $p$.

Motivation: this equation models expected value of iterated Gaussian linear system [like this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443143/when-is-prod-i-0-infty-i-x-i-x-it-0-for-isotropic-gaussian-x-i) for non-isotropic Gaussian case. Used to model training curve of neural network training.

Comment: I think the letter $h$ may be doing too many different jobs here.

Comment: Ah right, I got too used to frameworks just letting me add $1$ to a vector and various operations applying pointwise by default. Updated for clarity

Comment: Fully explicit equation is $x_i^{t+1}=(1-h_i)^2 x_i^t + h_i \sum_i x_i^t h_i$ , this form feels verbose

Comment: OK, so you are using $\mbox{diag}$ to build a diagonal matrix with the $(1-h_i)^2$

Comment: Yes, for $d\times d$ dynamics matrix $A$ we can write $A=\operatorname{diag}[(\mathbf{1}-\mathbf{h})^2]+\mathbf{h}\mathbf{h}^T$ so the question is how $\exp(At)$ behaves when $d$ approaches infinity

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365764/91764)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Just one question: what is substantially different here from what we discussed before?

Comment: @fedya The difference is that $d$ is assumed near infinite but h has specific form which gives hope for O(1) approach. Your earlier answer was was O(d) and was great in the context of original discussion which was motivated by a different (smaller) problem

Comment: Just group the entries: if you know them with $1\%$ precision (I'm afraid you cannot claim even that much), then you'll declare those between $0.99^k$ and $0.99^{k+1}$ exactly equal and play with $100\log d$ size, which is manageable up to $\log d=200$ with the previous technique, which gives $d$ not formally infinite, but certainly larger than the number of atoms in the visible universe. If you have an exact formula for $h$, we can think a bit and find a decent analytic approximation that is just a function of 2-4 variables.

Comment: PS If you have your entries in a decreasing order and have an oracle telling $h_i$ by $i$, founding the percentiles can be done by binary search pretty quickly too, so there is no need to guess anything but if you don't, then, as I said, you'd better tell us how we are supposed to just *read* the data first :-)

Comment: @fedya I have the exact formula for $h$ so I was looking for a decent analytic approximation. Entries of h add up to 1, and decay according to a power law with constant $p$

Comment: "Entries of h add up to 1, and decay according to a power law with constant p" And $p\in[1,2]$ as before or you want a wider range now?

Comment: $p$ is $\in (1, 2]$. Concrete problems I'm looking at have $p=1.009$, $p=1.064$, $p=1.033$, $p=1.101$, $p=1.4$ ([sources](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-velikanov-berthier-example.nb))

Comment: OK, give me a few days :-)

Comment: Apparently the $d\to \infty$ case reduces to a kind of "continuous mean-field model", the rank-1 term is the mean-field interaction